# Overloading new as a friend function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, operator-overloading, memory-management

For one of my classes, I'm writing a program that's going to be using a templated memory pool structure to handle the allocation of new instances of a class while keeping them together.  It is currently declared as follows:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int N>
class MemoryPool
{
    //Stuff
};
```

Where `T` is the class to create this pool for and `N` is the maximum number of elements that can be placed in the pool.  I want to overload `new` for the created type to make interactions with the pool a bit easier if it's a reasonable thing to do--but I'm not sure if it is.

My thoughts, currently, are that if it's possible to overload `new` as a friend function for `T`within `MemoryPool` that it *should* be doable from there but I'm not sure.  And, I'm not sure of the best way to start setting that up.  I've tried a few different ways to just declare the overloaded `new` and I'm getting errors before even implementing it.

- Is this a reasonable way to ensure that `new` is overridden for any class that uses `MemoryPool`?
- Is doing so even possible?
- Is doing so even a good idea?
- *How* would I set up the function declaration to accomplish this?

In case it matters, I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Note, the specific use of templates and overloading `new` are *not* part of the homework assignment.  It's just how I want to implement it if possible to make the rest of the assignment easier to read for the future.  So, if there's no reasonable way to do it, I just use member functions within `MemoryPool` to accomplish the same goal.

Thanks!

Example implementation:

```
MemoryPool<Object, MAX_OBJECTS> objectPool;  //Pool to store objects
Object*  allObjects[MAX_OBJECTS];            //Locations of objects

//Make a new object (this is how I'd like to do it)
allObjects[0] = new Object(/*args*/);

//(If I can't do the above, this would be the alternative)
allObjects[0] = objectPool.AllocateNewSlot();
allObjects[0]->Initialize(/*args*/);
```

In this example, the use of the `MemoryPool` takes care of the actual implementation of `new` ensuring the Object is created in its pool instead of just anywhere on the heap (to ensure all the Objects are in a centralized, more controllable location.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Could you add an example on how you would like to use it?

Comment: @ronag Updated with example implementation.  Does that help?

Comment: why not use a custom allocator / deleter with std::shared_ptr or unique_ptr?

Comment: @Rick I'm trying to avoid use of the STL or anything STL-like.  It's an unwritten spec of the assignment.  (But, yeah, I'm getting around that by writing my own Template...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to overload the new operator, however I would advice against it.

I think you are going in the wrong direction. You don't want to hide things and make users unsure what is happening. In this case you should be explicit that you are allocating through a pool.

Here is what you could do.

```
template<typename T, unsigned int N>
class MemoryPool
{
    T* malloc()
    {
        return ... // your pool impl
    }

    void free(T* ptr)
    {
        ... // your pool impl
    }

    void destory(T* ptr)
    {
        ptr->T::~T(); // call destructor
        free(ptr);
    }
};

int main()
{
    MemoryPool<my_class> pool;
    my_class* instance = new (pool.malloc()) my_class(/*args*/); // in-place new
    return 0;
}
```

You should also take a look at how [boost pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html) is implemented.

Comment: Good point on hiding vs being explicit here. I hadn't thought of that.